# Is there a limit to numbers of fields that can applied to use Tabular Form

Tags: apex

I have a table that contains 33 fields, and I was trying to use the Tabular Form.  when I click on the Apply Change,  Error msg such as 
"Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated update process. current row .... " appeared.
The Delete action has no issue.

Now, I tried on a smaller table that contains 5 fields, it ran smoothly.

Now both tables do not have Primary or and constrait at this point.
I am just using the wizard to create the form.

Is this a BUG??
Any advise how to do a workaround??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tabular form (4.2 and 5.0) [bug](http://apexbyg.blogspot.com/2015/05/tabular-form-bug.html) is your case.